# couchdb document without id error on update or creation

Tags: couchdb, updates, document, creation

I'm having trouble updating existing couch docs or creating new ones.
Whenever i try to update or create, i would get this error: Document without ID.
I confirm that the document sent to Couch DB doesn't have ID.
But its even weirder because my colleagues don't have that problem.
When they tried to do the same task, they would get the ID back from Couch DB.
I tried to install a new couch service and import couch documents from one of my teammates laptop, but no luck.
Is there a setting in couch that lets a document to be updated/created without an ID?
I'm newbie to couch db so please help.

Comment: Please let us know what commands you are using to update/create. You should be able to at least create documents without an ID, the database will generate one for you. Obviously you cannot update a document without telling the database the ID you want to update, so I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: @MikeRhodes the doc i want to update have the ID, but the new version of that doc doesn't have the id

Comment: It was fixed after i install CouchDB 1.0.2. Not sure what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To submit a document and have the server generate an ID you should submit a POST. But if you do this, you need to specify -H "Content-Type: application/json".

```
shell> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_db/ -d '{"test":"value"}'
```

Result:

```
{"ok":true,"id":"9b4789d9c67aa004f9ee1536990017d3","rev":"1-adde8b0266e0f8972b69c7144c2bded4"}
```

If you want to specify an ID for the document, you could do this:

```
chell> curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/my_db/"003" -d '{"test2":"value2"}'
```

Result:

```
{"ok":true,"id":"003","rev":"1-adde8b0266e0f8972b69c7144c2bded4"}
```

I am using version 2.0.0. Here is more information: [couchdb curl tutorial](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/intro/curl.html).

Comment: this issue was fixed by installing CouchDB 1.0.2.

Comment: interesting you say that. I was using 2.0 few weeks ago and I had that problem.

Comment: i think CouchDB team changed something in their code